# Django - model fields properties won't update

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

```
auth_id = models.CharField('something', max_length=14, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField('something', max_length=64)
email = models.EmailField('something', unique=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'something'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I'm currently updating the properties of `auth_id and email`.
None of the solutions I search worked.

Whenever I run the command `py manage.py makemigrations` then `py manage.py migrate` only the `max_length` is updated in the database. `null & blank` for auth_id and `unique` for email are not reflected on the database.

I'm using postgres.

Comment: I believe you have to run `manage.py makemigrations` first, before `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, i already run it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: `blank` is not a database constraint, it is only checked by Django, but `null` and `unique` should have been migrated. How do you check that they are not reflected on the database? Can you insert two records with the same email, for example? Can you edit your question and post the generated migration file?